# Show/Hide specific DIV when selecting an checkbox Button from a dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to setup a select checkbox Button from which, using jQuery, when select checkbox button will hide (opt2) DIV and unselect checkbox Then show div. I have most of the functionality working, I just can't get the hide DIV to displayed unSelect is selected. This is my code so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .desc{ display: none; }
</style>

<div> Delivery Details</div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="opt2">Same as Billing Details</label>
<div id="opt2" class="desc"> Billing Details Form</div>


$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='group1']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").show();
        $("#"+test).hide();
    }); 
});
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always showing both of the divs via class (`.desc`), and hiding the second. You're never hiding the first - even after two clicks it'll remain visible as you're using `show()`.

Replace `$("div.desc").show();`

with `$("div.desc").toggle();`

This will toggle the `show()` state, first click it'll show, second it'll hide etc.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tw9f/)

Comment: i want When I click checkBox then hide div...Onthe other hand show div

Answer (score 1):

pls try this

```
$("input[name$='group1']").click(function () {
    $("div.desc").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery) previous Stackoverflow post

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .desc{ display: none; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script src = "jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='group1']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        if($("div.desc").css('display') == 'none')
            $("div.desc").css('display','block');
        else if($("div.desc").css('display') == 'block')
            $("div.desc").css('display','none');
            //$("#"+test).hide();
    }); 
});
</script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="opt2">opt1</label>

<div id="opt1" class="desc">lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div id="opt2" class="desc">consectetur adipisicing</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved on Nisam answer:

```
$("input[name$='group1']").change(function () {
  $("div.desc").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

The onclick will miss keyboard alteration.